# Is it illegal directly putting in unicode in character-literal instead of using universal-character-name?

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode

According to ISO/IEC 14882:2011(§2.14.3), *character-literal*, which is also called constants, is illustrated as below.

```
character-literal:
    ’ c-char-sequence ’
    u’ c-char-sequence ’
    U’ c-char-sequence ’
    L’ c-char-sequence ’

...

c-char:
    any member of the source character set except
        the single-quote ’, backslash \, or new-line character
    escape-sequence
    universal-character-name
```

At a glance, it seems **directly putting in unicode instead of using *universal-character-name* in *character-literal*** is illegal. However most compilers, such as g++ and visual studio c++, do not bother at all with it, which is somewhat confusing. Does each implementation automatically convert these unicodes to *universal-character-name* before compile begins regardless of the standard?

Comment: _'Does each implementation automatically convert these unicodes to universal-character-name before compile begins regardless of the standard?'_ I wouldn't rely on this, but I'd guess clang also supports it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm aware that clang also supports it. However i couldn't find any clear statements from the standard.

Comment: Wouldn't that just depend on what your "source character set" is?

Comment: @KerrekSB I thought source character set is same as _basic-source-character-set_. Am i wrong?

Comment: @user3647351: Unfortunately yes. It looks like the term "source character set" is not very clearly emphasized, it only occurs in a couple of grammatical specifications. Its description is the implemention-defined "set of physical source characters accepted" (2.2/1).

Comment: @KerrekSB Do you mean to say source character set is different from _basic-source-character-set_? Does ISO/IEC 14882:2011 also illustrate not only _basic-source-character-set_ but also source character set?

Comment: Yes, one is a superset of the other. It's implied by that phrase I cited in the previous comment. It might be best if you just read Clause 2 yourself, though.

Comment: Cheers. The upshot is that you can always write any program using only the *basic* set (by expressing everything non-basic in universal-character-name literals, like `\uXXXX`), but you may equivalently type those non-basic characters directly in your code if your system offers an encoding that contains your desired characters (e.g. UTF-8).

Comment: It seems there is no difference according to Bjarne Stroustrup. He said _I don't think that there is a difference_ via email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the first "phase of translation" handles that (C++11 2.2/1:1.):

> Any source file character not in the basic source character set (2.3) is replaced by the universal-character-name that designates that character.

So your input files are encoded in the source character set, which includes the basic source character set, but in the program text all non-basic characters are replaced by their universal-character-name.

Answer (score 3):

It's implementation-defined:

§2.2 Phases of translation:

> 1. [...] The set of physical source file characters accepted is implementation-defined. [...] Any source file character not in the basic
>      source character set (2.3) is replaced by the universal-character-name that designates that character. (An implementation may use any internal encoding, so long as an actual extended character
>      encountered in the source file, and the same extended character expressed in the source file as a
>      universal-character-name (i.e., using the \uXXXX notation), are handled equivalently [...].)